# Javascript - Sound

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Is there anyway to play a sound file WITHOUT user CLICKS or MOUSE OVERS?

I have a scoreboard that I would like to play a sound file when the team scores. Any pointers would be appreciated. I am basically done the scoreboard but don't have sound.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @user1883309 Whatever you call when a team scores, just place a `var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
audio.play();`

Comment: Nothing yet, I have posted my code to see if any one could guide me to where this should go? Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Thanks  Lemony-Andrew  the code worked and was able to implemented calling an if statement.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/admsev/jquery-play-sound

```
$.playSound('http://example.org/sound.mp3');
```

or

```
document.getElementById('yourAudioTag').play();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response I added code to see where to implement these suggestions. Just learning scripting.